# how to get array unique from multidimensional array when contains associative array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-unique

I have a multi-dimensional array that contains an associative array in every row. How to make it unique based on specified array key?

I already tried some method like:

```
$cart = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $cart)));
```

But failed to produce data as my expect my array structure look like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
 (
 [product_code] => prod3
 [qty] => 7
 )
[1] => Array
 (
 [product_code] => prod3
 [qty] => 1
 )
[2] => Array
 (
 [product_code] => prod4
 [qty] => 7
 )
[3] => Array
 (
 [product_code] => prod4
 [qty] => 7
 )
)
```

and I expect to get this result after using array `array_unique()` method. Just 2 records remaining:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
 (
 [product_code] => prod3
 [qty] => 1
 )
[2] => Array
 (
 [product_code] => prod4
 [qty] => 7
 )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to convert the array into an associative array. Which will override duplicate values. Use `array_values` to convert the associative array into a simple array.

```
$arr = //Your array

$result = array_values(array_column( $arr , null, 'product_code' ));

print_r( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_code] => prod3
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_code] => prod4
            [qty] => 7
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: ...you know I like this one!

Comment: @mickmackusa Lol. I bet you do. You are the one who taught me this one :)

Comment: I ever try with simple case not so complicated as this case